# Planned Imgur Maintenance for Thursday, February 23rd 00:00-01:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, announcements, imgur, maintenance

On Thursday, February 23rd, between 00:00 and 01:00 UTC (February 22nd between 7:00 and 8:00 pm EST), Imgur is performing routine maintenance for 10-15 minutes, which may cause interruptions to `stack.imgur.com`, the hosting provider we use for post content and user submitted avatars.

- This will impact the ability to upload new images to Imgur across the network, including in chat.
- Some users may receive 404s when requesting image links on the site during this window, although most GET requests will be cached by fastly, so only for new images sizes that haven't been requested before or expired cache results.

Will update here when the update has started and when it is complete.

Comment: *runs `crontab -l | grep BrokenImageRepairer`* - yeah, that should work. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Is this a first of a kind announcement? I have never seen an announcement for Imgur maintenance (I'm not implying that  this announcement is bad; I'm just wondering if this is the first time a planned Imgur maintenance is announced through Meta).

Comment: @RandomPerson, I *believe* so - but someone might dig through meta and find some prior art.

Comment: What about including a warning when attempting to upload an image?

Comment: @dan1st, while there might be a chance to optimize the UX in cases like these, the end result will be the same... user tries to upload image and either gets our custom maintenance error message or the regular error message from the service being down. Which would also require writing net new code to handle, so we likely won't be doing it for a 10-15 minute window during low traffic times of day.  That said, if similar situtaions arise in the future or for longer planned outages, I could see trying to better notify users at the point of error.

Answer (score 12):

The update was to increase disk space on an AWS RDS instance.

- **Update Started** - `2023-02-23 12:08 AM UTC`
- **Update Operational** - `2023-02-23 12:14 AM UTC`

  AWS currently in [storage optimization state](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-stuck-in-storage-optimization/), but should be fully operational

  We've observed zero down time and haven't seen any interruption of service or error logs so far.  Will post back with when DB instance returns to "Available State", but that can take from 2-24 hrs according to AWS
- **Update Complete** - `2023-02-23 01:20 AM UTC`

  As proof of completion, I offer into evidence this newly created image on imgur:

  [image]

Comment: Yay! All done :)